# Rancher OS: generate data in one container and set as environment variable in another container

Tags: php, linux, shell, docker, rancher

I guess I have a pretty specific question.
Multiple docker containers are running in a stack already.
Now two of these containers need to talk to each other with a secure connection.
For this Container A is able to generate a Token that Container B should set

My problem is now: how is it possible to start Container A, wait until it fully loaded (PHP Framework that takes some time to fully load) then generates a token, sets this Token for Container B as environment variable, then start Container B.

Or is there any better way to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why not B querying A? `B->A`

Answer (score 0):

If your container A has Rancher API keys, you can communicate with Rancher API and launch container B with whatever environment variables or labels you want.